# Iterate through nested Objects in React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-props

I have this json from my API:

```
 {
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Titel one',
      image: {
        image: "https://imagepath"
        crops: [
          {
            height: 150
            path: "https://imagepath"
            type: "small"
            width: 200
          },
          {
            height: 350
            path: "https://imagepath"
            type: "large"
            width: 600
          }

        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Titel two',
      image: {
        image: "https://imagepath"
        crops: [
          {
            height: 150
            path: "https://imagepath"
            type: "small"
            width: 200
          },
          {
            height: 350
            path: "https://imagepath"
            type: "large"
            width: 600
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In a child `List.js` component I `map` over the array:

```
function List(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.posts.map(post => (
        <Card key={post.id} image={post.image} title={post.titel} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

To render the `id`, `title` and `image` works just fine.

But I need to render a specific **image path** from a crops-type e.g `small`. How do I achieve that?

**Update:**

In my  component I added the following:

```
function Card({ image, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <figure>
    {image.crops
      .filter(cropType => cropType.type === 'small')
      .map(filteredURL => (
        <img src={filteredURL.path} alt={title} />
      ))}
  </figure>
      <div>
        <h2>
          {title}
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is this a good and clean solution? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use inside the `.map()` an other `.map()` to pick up values from `post.image.crops`. Or `.filter()` to render only the value `small`.

Comment: So you mean before I render <Card /> component?

Comment: It depends where and how you would like to see the details of value `small`. But in my previous comment I meant to be inside of the current `.map()`.

Comment: You've to use the map method again inside Card component, like `this.props. image.crops.map((corpItem, index) => <span key={index}>{corpItem.type}</span>)`

Comment: @norbitrial Thanks I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following. I believe you're wanting the image object that corresponds to the `small` crop. I broke up your components into two to separate the concerns more.

```
// The Card component should be able to handle nullish values or have this component check to see if there is an image, title, etc. for each index.
function ListItem({ id, image, title }) {
  const croppedImage = image.crops.find((crop) => crop.type === 'small');
  return <Card image={croppedImage} key={id} title={title} />;
};

function List({ posts }) {
  const items = posts.map((post) => <ListItem {...post} />);
  return <div>{items}</div>;
};
```